# Success notification in Jenkins Job if any of the protractor suite fails except last

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I have around 4 Protractor Suites which are running in Jenkins. The status of the job is decided on Suite 4. How to make the job fail if any of the suite fails?

I am using the following command in Execute shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
npm install
npm run e2e -- --suite="validation" --baseUrl="https://www.example.com#"
npm run e2e -- --suite="publishObject" --baseUrl="https://www.example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

check this feature I hope it help you failFast = true

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

In case of failFast = true, as soon as one of the jobs fail, the whole pipeline run will fail and won't continue running all other suites

Comment: Please add how this feature is beneficial in OP's case.

Comment: Please add this in your answer.